# When setting up OpenLDAP for the first time, what are some things to keep in mind?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm in the process of reading up on documentation and setting up OpenLDAP to handle authentication throughout my network, for email, web services, user accounts, any anything else that I could throw at it. It's not going to be anything SUPER big, but I want it to feel live, since I'm doing it in my home lab.

What are some good things to keep in mind or something to make sure I always remember when setting up OpenLDAP? Should I make sure that I always travel over SSL? Should I use Kerbeos? Anything would be appreciated to keep in mind.

Comment: Are you going to use Windows in this environment at all? If so, consider a Samba implementation, or even Active directory instead of OpenLDAP.

Comment: Most likely not, but there is nothing saying that there wont be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A partial list in no particular order:

- Use `cn=config` (see `man slapd-config`).
- Set up [Master-Master](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html#N-Way%20Multi-Master%20%22Master-Master) replication at your core.
- Always use some sort of encryption for authentication.
- LDAPS (port 636) is deprecated in favor of STARTTLS for LDAP.
- SASL-GSSAPI and SASL-EXTERNAL are useful if you don't like entering passwords a lot.
- Disable SASL mechanism you don't support.
- Don't use the root DN when you don't have to.
- Pay attention to your ACLs (e.g. users should not have write access to `uidNumber` and `gidNumber`).
- `ldapseach -x -H $URI` is a an anonymous search. (`ldapwhoami -x -H $URI`).
- Limited local replicas can be much better than `nscd` (self access via `ldapi:///`).
- Overlay `memberof` is very handy for group membership.

Probably important:
**Understand the [documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/)**. It's not everything you need, but it sure helps.

Comment: Question, what exactly do you mean by Master-Master replication at the core?

Comment: @Chiggins You should not have master server, but master *servers*. I prefer N-Way multimaster. Mirror-Mode is also a decent option. I've edited in an attempt to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

### SSL Libraries

Debian(and thus Ubuntu) package OpenLDAP compiled against gnuTLS instead of OpenSSL. This is fine for playing around, but gnuTLS has been significantly slower on our network. I always rebuild the Ubuntu package compiled against OpenSSL.

Other distros may do the same or different.

### Kerberos

Kerberos doesn't really seem useful in my environment(~200 linux workstations, ~40 macs, nfs servers, imap, smtp, web server). None of our common client applications support kerberos authentication(Firefox, Thunderbird). It would just be used on a host level for NFS and as a PAM module for authentication. I think SSL can do just as good a job at keeping passwords secret.

If you do use kerberos, you should use Heimdal for integration with the OpenLDAP smbk5pwd overlay.

### Client Libraries

The default library for nss from PADL is a bit bloated and troublesome. I recommend you try [SSS](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/) or nss-pam-ldapd. They both work very well in my environment.

SSS does so much more than PADL's libraries. It includes caching, so you don't need nscd.

[nss-pam-ldapd](http://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/) is a rewrite of the PADL libraries made to be much more efficient.

### Managing your data

I am a big fan of [phpLDAPAdmin](http://phpldapadmin.sf.net/). It makes it very easy to view your schemas and modify individual entries.

### Other LDAP Servers

They may be slower, but they have more advanced features.

You might want to try ApacheDS since it has builtin kerberos.

Comment: There is so much to say here. Should I turn this answer into a community wiki?

Comment: +1 for the gnuTLS note -- I've found gnuTLS to be impractcally slow for production workloads, and quite frankly OpenSSL has more extensive adoption, and thus more complete testing.

Answer (score 2):

This question is really too broad to answer, and any answer would be heavily dependent on your environment.

Some things **I** would consider are:

- Does LDAP make sense as the authentication system?

  - If not, what might be better?
- Does LDAP make sense as the authorization system?
  *(authorization would be things like `sudoers`)*

  - If not, what might be better?
- What kind of security makes sense?

  - SSL? (pretty much definitely)
  - Kerberos? (Does everything support it? WILL everything support it in the future?)
  - What about security within LDAP itself (ACLs)

    - Object/Subtree permissions
    - Browsable/Searchable by... (anyone (anonymous), registered users, admins, etc...)
    - How will users change their password?
- How will we get the individual workstations to respect LDAP information?

  - pam_ldap/nss_ldap? (old & busted, but works)
  - pam_ldapd (new hotness: Fewer LDAP connections, other benefits, but some unimplemented features)
- Will we have to interact with Windows - **EVER**?
  (If you say "yes" here you really need to use AD as the LDAP server)